# Cypress run test from cmd

Tags: jenkins, cypress

Hi I installed Cypress with `npm install cypress` and I got some test cases, which are in

```
C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\Cytest\cypress\integration\examples
```

What I want is firstly run my test cases ('test1,'test2') form cmd line after then I can use them with Jenkins to CI/CD (Note that I'm a student at Uni. so I'm just beginner)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options, check it in the docs [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line.html#How-to-run-commands). You can run it like:

```
$(npm bin)/cypress run
```

or

```
./node_modules/.bin/cypress run
```

or

```
npx cypress run
```

Answer (score 0):

add below code in package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "cypress open"
  }
}
```

and run cypress with npm run test